# Bash random function behavior when using trap USR1

Tags: bash, shell, signals

I have a bash code that gives me random results.
I have stripped down my code to some pseudo code that looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function TrapQuit {
    echo "Quitting"
}

function SubFunction {
    echo "Full function call tree ${FUNCNAME[@]}"
}

function DisPatch {
    echo "Running function ${FUNCNAME[0]}"
    SubFunction "1"
}

function test {
    kill -USR1 $$

}

trap DisPatch USR1
trap TrapQuit EXIT HUP

test &
test &
test &
test &
test &

while true; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Basically, ${FUNCNAME[@]} should list all function calls from current function up to main.
When I run this code, I get randomly different results.

The good result is:

`Running function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch main
Running function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch main
Running function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch main
Running function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch test main
^CRunning function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch main
Quitting`

The strange result is:

`Running function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch main
Running function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch main
Running function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch DisPatch main
Running function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch SubFunction DisPatch DisPatch main
Running function DisPatch
Full function call tree SubFunction DisPatch main
^CQuitting`

Once every three or five runs, I get the weird result where DisPatch function is three times in ${FUNCNAME[@]}.

How can the DisPatch function end up multiple times in ${FUNCNAME[@]} from SubFunction where it seems that DisPatch has executed itself recursively ?

Thanks for any insight.

Tested with

GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) under CentOS 7

GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) under Fedora 24

Comment: What did you expect the output to be when a signal handler is invoked while running an existing signal handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. First, `$$` is always the process ID of the top-most shell; subshells do not reset its value. Use `kill -USR1 $BASHPID` instead. Second, subprocesses do not inherit traps. You need to move `trap DisPath USR1` into the definition of `test`.

In the end, your `test` should look like

```
function test {
    trap DisPatch USR1
    kill -USR1 $BASHPID
}
```

Comment: Well I am trying to reach the main process from the test subshells, so using $$ and leaving the trap in the main process works.
What I am not understanding is the multiple consecutive DisPatch call when printing ${FUNCNAME[@]}. Could you care to explain ?

Comment: I wonder if this is just multiple background processes trying to write to the console at the same time?As in, there's no explicit synchronisation on who gets to write first completely/atomically